# can't get email address from Facebook SDK v5 for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to get User's email address after Logging from Facebook using their PHP SDK V5, but running into issues which i don't quite understand.

According to their Step by Step Guide https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/5.0.0

I create Login.php and Login-callback.php files

**Login.php**

```
session_start() ;
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile']; // optional
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://www.example.com/login-callback.php', $permissions);


echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
```

**Login-callback.php**

```
session_start() ;
require_once __DIR__ . '/src/Facebook/autoload.php';

# login-callback.php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $app_id,
  'app_secret' => $app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (isset($accessToken)) {
  // Logged in!
  $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

  // OAuth 2.0 client handler
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
$longLivedAccessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($_SESSION['facebook_access_token']);


// Sets the default fallback access token so we don't have to pass it to each request
$fb->setDefaultAccessToken($longLivedAccessToken);

try {
  $response = $fb->get('/me');
  $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName();

$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');  // This is not getting any thing

echo $email; // Empty

}
```

The graphObject->getProperty('email');  is not returning anything

Comment: You need to ask for the email field

Comment: How do i do that?  Because i tried to to make a request like this $request = new FacebookRequest(
  $longLivedAccessToken,
  'GET',
  '/me'
);
$response = $request->execute();
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
$email = $graphObject->getProperty('email');

Comment: It gave me Fatal error: Class 'FacebookRequest' not found

Comment: `$fb->get('/me?fields=email');`

Comment: @WizKid, you should post this as an answer

Answer (score 7):

My problem was the same. My site recognized the login, I received only name and id.

I saw this hint here:

```
$fb->get('/me?fields=email');
```

This fixed my problem!

Comment: But you only get an email if the user added a valid one. See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user

Comment: As @Norbert wrote, it's clearly [documented](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions#reference-email): _Note, even if you request the `email` permission it is not guaranteed you will get an email address. For example, if someone signed up for Facebook with a phone number instead of an email address, the email field may be empty._

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Facebook's own [Login Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) (generated via their tool plugin generator) in your php file which would be more appealing, but remember to take care of this HTML5 attribute **data-scope**.
Check this example:

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" 
   data-size="large" data-button-type="login_with" data-show-faces="false"
   data-scope="email" data-auto-logout-link="false" 
   data-use-continue-as="false">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should fetch user account information using Facebook Graph API method. After getting successful access token, use api graph method. Like that:

```
$userProfile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,gender,locale,picture');

$userClass = new User;
$userData = $userClass->checkFBUserData($userProfile);
```

Than you can print email address like that: `echo $userData['email'];`

For more detail please check [this tutorial](https://www.codefixup.com/login-with-facebook/)

This is working source, I have tested it